# Always getting null value when checking the Database before inserting data

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have created a method to check the database every time data is added to it. The reason for this is to check for duplicate primary keys(manually generated).The problem I'm facing is that the method always returns null value even when the data exists in the database.

Here's my code :

```
public int checkComRegnumberAvailable(string conRegnumber)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RegNumber  FROM OtherCompanyData";
        con.Open();
        //string result = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        string result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (result.Equals(conRegnumber))
        {
            return 1;
        }


        else
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `SELECT RegNumber  FROM OtherCompanyData` returns any data? Did you try it on Management Studio or something? If `result ` is `null`, that means your command returns empty set. `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is useless in your case. It doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: You can't use ExecuteScalar when you're using a `select`like that. The select will return a list of records (even thought the record only contains the one value per record). What you're actually looking for, is if an record with the `conRegnumber` value already exists?

Comment: @SteenTøttrup [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx): _returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query_

Comment: @SteenTøttrup He _can_ use `ExecuteScalar` with `SELECT`. It just returns first row of the first column. Other columns or rows are ignored.

Comment: @SonerGönül okay, so he can, but how does it make sense in the example he has given?

Comment: can someone tell me how to change this method to check whether the particular value is already available or not in the database.

Comment: @Madushi you can add `where` in query

Answer (score -1):

You can to use a DataReader in order to retrive informatiom from your database. The link below shows a fine example of how to use it in your code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No it doesn't _need_. `ExecuteScalar` do what OP wants exactly. And this is a link-only answer. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @SonerGönül Edited my answer now. In my past experience I was always using SqlDataReaders whilst retrieving information from the database, be it one field or many, hence I thought that would be what OP is looking for.